# Rails 3.x I made the mistake of using the asset_sync gem and now my application does not display any css on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am extremely confused.  Made a big mistake of using the asset_sync gem and now my assets are not being used in production with heroku.  Prior to installing the gem and following the documentation, my site was working perfectly in production.  At this point, I don't even want to use this gem AT ALL anymore.  I have removed the gem, but for some reason heroku is STILL calling my css/js files under their aliases that I had originally stated in my production.rb file.  I have reverted back to my code in production.rb to before i ever installed the gem and went through the steps that were described in the documentation.  My question:  how can I possibly find/remove what is causing my css and js to not work in heroku?  I apologize if I am missing any vital information in my post as it is my first time posting on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I think You've missed to configure this. in your

1. environments/stage.rb
2. environments/production.rb

   `config.action_controller.asset_host = s3_assets_host` or any CDN

If you still do not intend to use AssetSync Gem Try removing `/public/assets/manifest.yml` file

Comment: Thank you for the response Ronak.  I have already removed my manifest.yml file, but still no luck.  The strange part here is that this does not only cause issues on the app that i configured for asset_sync.  Now when i attempt to run any app locally, my assets are not served at all.  The issue still persists on heroku as well.  when i run heroku config:    DATABASE_URL:postgres://lqfiiaibkesvcg:QeNlVnHyy2PumHnWXbHIjRWXux@ec2-107-22-173-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d3mmrtpncq5u3f

Comment: Can you please put the stack trace, if you get any error. I'd like to see your layouts application.html file.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I'm trying to get rid of all traces of asset_sync also and it's still using the 'production/assets' for my bootstrap icons.  It's driving me crazy and I can't figure out where it's coming from.  I ran a search and it came up empty.